# How to declare a constructor in User defined datatype?

Tags: java, constructor

I am passing a double dimensional array as the parameter in the constructor. This constructor is supposed to create a node of the datatype using the array. How can this be done? I am not getting an idea.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass (int[][] twoDArray) {//constructor
        Node node = new Node(....);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use something like that in the constructor I fear. The API strictly forbids it, as it hasn't allowed anything like that to be created in the class